# javascript - testing against custom attributes in loop

Tags: javascript, html, custom-attributes

I have a form that I set up as a quiz to take. Eventually I will alter it to calculate the final score of the quiz once done. But I am stuck on this one part. I want to add a point if a right box is checked, and subtract a point if a wrong box is checked.

Code for a right answer:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="q3" id="q1javascript" answer="true">
```

Code for wrong answer:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="q3" id="q3xhtml" answer="false">
```

Javascript checking against it:

```
function test() {
    var boxes = document.getElementsbyName('q3');
    var score = 0;
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 4) {
        var answer = boxes[i].getAttribute('answer');
        if (answer === 'true') {
            score++;
        }
        else {
            score--;
        }
        i++;
    }
    alert(score);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjsc16x/LMabz/)

Comment: Your jsfiddle can't work. Please fix it first.

Comment: Are your users inexperienced enough to not spot `answer="true"` in HTML?

Comment: custom attributes are not valid, and if you are to use anything it would be in HTML5 and data-* attributes. Albeit invalid for other doctypes it is still the best way to go.

Comment: DO you really want to keep an attribute in the html itself which says what the options are. It will be easy for a user to look at the html source to find out the answers for your questions. :) Probably you should think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vCz2T/1/

The checkboxes now use `data-answer="true"` or `data-answer="false"`. Any custom data like your `answer` attribute should be prefixed with `data-`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="q3" id="q3css" data-answer="true">
```

The `test()` function has been changed to be:

```
function test() {
    var boxes = document.getElementsByName('q3');
    var score = 0;
    var i, box, answer;
    for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        box = boxes[i];
        if (box.checked) {
            answer = box.getAttribute('data-answer');
            if (answer === 'true') {
                score++;
            } else {
                score--;
            }
        }
    }
    alert(score);
}
```

You now have to do `getAttribute('data-answer')`. Also, you should check for `box.checked` so that only checked checkboxes are counted.

Comment: Almost there-- OP wanted the score to be incremented on a checkbox matching true, and decremented on a checkbox matching false.  This solution doesn't do that.